# google play store does not count downloads for referrer is 'other'?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Currently I am providing Direct link to users through local adv. campaigns.
example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc.xyz

I am Daily getting about 1500-2000 downloads.It is also shown by my analytics.but, google play store is counting only 50-100 downloads per day. has anyone faced the same issue?

is it wrong way to provide link for app directly?

note:-my analytics shows that for about 90% downloads referrer is 'other'.I am confused if direct link is provided to play store why it is showing referrer as other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i faced this issue. Google playstore update the download count later on. If you need immediately, you can ask from playstore contact right from there. But surely it will update.

Comment: I am facing this issue from last 2 weeks,how much time it took for you to correct your downloads.

Comment: may be 3 to 4 weeks Nik, i send queries to google play support after they update it.